# Tagging someone on Discord with python

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my first time making bot on Discord, i wanted to tag a member on my channel with a message in it. My code is like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('|bro'):
        await message.channel.send("You are dumb" + the member)
```

And the message should be like this: `"You are dumb @themember"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ping the author just include `message.author.mention` in your reply.

The ".mention" pings the user as if you were using the @ symbol.